# mounting an .iso file into a directory and replacing all of its content

Tags: linux

I was trying to install matlab on my linux (mint) computer, using some of the .iso files. I was trying to mount one of them using the command

```
mount R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /home/.../Documents/
```

which seems to have mounted the .iso file into my Documents directory and replaced everything there. When I try and open up the Documents directory, it just contains the contents of the .iso file and none of the files which I know were in there previously.

If I go to, say libre office, and click 'open recent file', any of my recent files which were in my documents now don't exist. This is quite worrying as I have a lot of work in there which isn't backed up.

I don't really know anything about what mount does. Will it have permanently deleted all the files from my Documents directory? I can 'unmount' the Documents directory now, but am worried it might be a bad idea and permanently delete the stuff that used to be there. Can anyone help me try and recover my Documents directory?

thanks

Comment: Unmount it, and all your files will be there.

Comment: try man mount..

Comment: unmounted it and it all returned. thanks! panic over.

Comment: Well, no harm done. FWIW I usually create a temporary, empty directory, e.g., `/mnt/tmp` to mount images and what-not on. That way I don't end up hiding something I need :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.